# What’s a word to describe an opinion given by someone not qualified to give it?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in, I find your assertion that this issue is of minimal importance to be (————).

Comment: "Uncorroborated" would work, though it doesn't have exactly that meaning.

Comment: +1, also *unsupported* or (more of a zing!) *insupportable*. *Untenable* works in a political setting (both for the argument and the position of the arguer). Apologies for regurgitating the thesaurus.

Comment: to be ***baseless***

Answer (score 1):

Two specific words and one phrase:

1. If the answer sounded good, but is incorrect, with an implication of intentional deception, then it may be ***specious*** [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specious)]:

   > *2. having deceptive attraction or allure*
2. A similar word with (as I learned it, anyway) a slightly different nuance (of randomness rather than malicious intent), is ***spurious*** [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spurious)]:

   > · false and not what it appears to be, or (of reasons and judgments) based on something that has not been correctly understood and therefore false

Although I see several dictionaries giving almost identical definitions, the latter has always been used in e.g. a laboratory setting to describe a chance result, whereas the former definitely implies mendacity.

Interestingly, the etymology for *specious* [[etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/specious)] is from the Latin for *good-looking, beautiful, fair*; and *spurious* [[Ibidem](https://www.etymonline.com/word/spurious)] likewise, *illegitimate, false*.

The phrase I had in mind was ***back-seat driver***, though I gather they just as annoying even if they *are* qualified to give the opinion.

There are others ["out of their depth", "stunning example of the Peter Principle in action", "victim of the Dunning-Kruger Effect"] but they, too, would all require rewriting your sentence to refer to the *someone* rather than the *opinion*.

Answer (score 1):

You might try

[ill-informed](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ill-informed) - resulting from inadequate knowledge about a situation or subject.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a sense of disdain in the wording of the question. Possibly "**boobish**" would be fitting to describe such an "**ill-conceived**" opinion.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/boobish

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ill-conceived

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'anecdotal'.

I find your assertion that this issue is of minimal importance to be 'anecdotal'.

Anecdotal: (of an account) not necessarily true or reliable, because based on personal accounts rather than facts or research.
"while there was much anecdotal evidence there was little hard fact."

//en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anecdotal